# JSON.parse is different in Node and Chrome?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
code :
JSON.parse('{"a":"\\\\"}');

node: { a: '\\' }
chrome: {a: "\"}
```

Why it behaves different between Node and Chrome? I've check the v8 version of them and both are 5.x, it's weird.

Answer (score 3):

It's just a difference in the presentation of the object contents by the console implementations. If you do

```
console.log(JSON.parse('{"a":"\\\\"}').a.length)
```

in both environments you correctly get `1`.

The Node console seems to want to show you the object contents such that you could re-create the object with cut-and-paste. The Chrome console just shows the single backslash, but there's just one backslash for real in both environments.

Comment: Worth to note that this has nothing to do with `JSON.parse`. Same goes for `console.log({"a":"\\"});`